# comparing version numbers in c

Tags: c, string-comparison, version-numbering

I am seeing a lot of answers for this problem in other languages but I am trying to find out a way to compare 2 version numbers given as strings.  For example

```
str1 = "141.1.23"
str2 = "141.1.22"
```

I am trying to find a way to compare the integer values in the strings to see which one is larger. (In this case str1 would be larger).  I thought about using sometime of combination with atoi and strtok but I know I wont be able to tokenize 2 strings at once.  Any advice?

Comment: For this example `strcmp` would do :-)

Comment: Mmm, stcmp would probably put Linux 2.14 before Linux 2.4.

Comment: @David Grayson: strcmp returns a value greater than zero when the first character that does not match has a greater value in str1 than in str2, and the comparison stops on the first nul, so it will still work, even for 2.1 and 2.14.  2.1 and 2.10 might be ambiguous, but then it is any way.  It is by no means clear from the examples what constitutes a valid version string in this case.  It will work so long as all digit groups except the last are the same length so you don't end up comparing a digit with a dot.

Comment: Ya sorry I realized that as soon as I typed it so deleted the comment :).

Comment: C++ version of this question for those interested: [How to compare version numbers in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33135019)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I know I wont be able to tokenize 2 strings at once.

Fortunately, you do not need to: make a function that takes a string, and parses it for three integer numbers using `strtok_r` (use a reentrant version, it's a lot safer).

```
strunct version_t {
    int major;
    int minor;
    int build;
};

version_t parse_ver(const char* version_str) {
    version_t res;
    // Use strtok_r to split the string, and atoi to convert tokens to ints
    return res;
}
```

Now you can call `parse_ver` twice, get two `version_t` values, and compare them side-by-side.

P.S. If you adopt a convention to always pad the numbers with leading zeros to a specific length, i.e. make sure that you write `"141.1.03"` and not `"141.1.3"`, you could substitute integer comparison with lexicographic one.

Comment: With respect to the fixed field length suggestion, it is not clear from the example in the question that this is not the case.  It is at best poorly specified.

Answer (score 14):

I really wonder why people strive for such complicated solutions when there is `sscanf` in C. Here is a very simple solution to that problem that will work for 99% of all use cases:

```
int compVersions ( const char * version1, const char * version2 ) {
    unsigned major1 = 0, minor1 = 0, bugfix1 = 0;
    unsigned major2 = 0, minor2 = 0, bugfix2 = 0;
    sscanf(version1, "%u.%u.%u", &major1, &minor1, &bugfix1);
    sscanf(version2, "%u.%u.%u", &major2, &minor2, &bugfix2);
    if (major1 < major2) return -1;
    if (major1 > major2) return 1;
    if (minor1 < minor2) return -1;
    if (minor1 > minor2) return 1;
    if (bugfix1 < bugfix2) return -1;
    if (bugfix1 > bugfix2) return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Here, give it a try:
https://ideone.com/bxCjsb

Comment: This implementation is brilliant. Should be up-voted more.

Answer (score 5):

The following routine compares version-number strings that are made up of genuine numbers. The advantage is that the delimiter does not matter; it will work with, for example, 141.01.03, 141:1:3, or even 141A1P3. It also handles mismatched tails so that 141.1.3 will come before 141.1.3.1.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int versionCmp( char *pc1, char *pc2)
{
    int result = 0;
    /* loop through each level of the version string */
    while (result == 0) {
        /* extract leading version numbers */
        char* tail1;
        char* tail2;
        unsigned long ver1 = strtoul( pc1, &tail1, 10 );
        unsigned long ver2 = strtoul( pc2, &tail2, 10 );
        /* if numbers differ, then set the result */
        if (ver1 < ver2)
            result = -1;
        else if (ver1 > ver2)
            result = +1;
        else {
            /* if numbers are the same, go to next level */
            pc1 = tail1;
            pc2 = tail2;
            /* if we reach the end of both, then they are identical */
            if (*pc1 == '\0' && *pc2 == '\0')
                break;
            /* if we reach the end of one only, it is the smaller */
            else if (*pc1 == '\0')
                result = -1;
            else if (*pc2 == '\0')
                result = +1;
            /*  not at end ... so far they match so keep going */
            else {
                pc1++;
                pc2++;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}

int main( void )
{
    assert(versionCmp("1.2.3" , "1.2.3" ) == 0);
    assert(versionCmp("1.2.3" , "1.2.4" )  < 0);
    assert(versionCmp("1.2.4" , "1.2.3" )  > 0);
    assert(versionCmp("10.2.4", "9.2.3" )  > 0);
    assert(versionCmp("9.2.4",  "10.2.3")  < 0);
    /* Trailing 0 ignored. */
    assert(versionCmp("01", "1") == 0);
    /* Any single space delimiter is OK. */
    assert(versionCmp("1a2", "1b2") == 0);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Replace the `strtoul`s with `strcspn`s and a `strncmp`, and you can use it to compare non-numeric version "numbers" -- but the delimiter must be a dot. For example, 141.3A.1 sorts before 141.3B.

```
...
while (result == 0) {
    /* ignore leading zeroes */
    pc1 += strspn( pc1, "0" );
    pc2 += strspn( pc2, "0" );
    /* extract leading version strings */
    int len1 = strcspn( pc1, "." );
    int len2 = strcspn( pc2, "." );
    /* if one is shorter than the other, it is the smaller version */
    result = len1 - len2;
    /* if the same length then compare as strings */
    if (result == 0)
        result = strncmp( pc1, pc2, len1 );
    if (result == 0) {
        pc1 += len1;
        pc2 += len2;
        if (*pc1 == '\0' && *pc == '\0')
            ...
```

Comment: For a more thorough malicious integer input checking: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12923949/895245

Comment: In your second example "." could be replaced by a string of valid delimiters like ".:-" in order to eliminate the restriction that the delimiter must be a dot.

Answer (score 2):

**`strverscmp` glibc extension**

- `man strverscmp`
- http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/String_002fArray-Comparison.html

Example:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    assert(strverscmp("1.2.3" , "1.2.3" ) == 0);
    assert(strverscmp("1.2.3" , "1.2.4" )  < 0);
    assert(strverscmp("1.2.3" , "1.2.2" )  > 0);
    assert(strverscmp("9.2.3" , "10.2.3")  < 0);
    assert(strverscmp("10.2.3", "9.2.3" )  > 0);

    /* Delimiers are also compared. */
    assert(strverscmp("1a2", "1b2" ) < 0);
    assert(strverscmp("1b2", "1a2" ) > 0);

    /* Leading 0s: number gets treated as 0.X, e.g. 01 means 0.1.
     * Maybe not perfect for version strings, but sane version strings
     * should not have leading 0s. 
     */
    assert(strverscmp("01", "9" ) < 0);
    assert(strverscmp("01", "09") < 0);
    assert(strverscmp("01", "09") < 0);
    assert(strverscmp("09",  "1") < 0);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Source: https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=string/strverscmp.c;h=96d4227cd50090f3a7c45e7241d817d34e42f5ce;hb=cbc06bc486635347ee0da51d04a82eedf51602d5#l42

Tested on Glibc 2.21, Ubuntu 15.10.

**`filevercmp` from gnulib**

Yet another GNU implementation. Source: http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/gnulib.git/tree/libfilevercmp.c?id=71be4c87c8267369f40fbfab7523ab9847154c02#n125

It is used in [`sort -V`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/sort.c?id=v8.23#n2586) of Coreutils 8.23, which works like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4024263/895245

Answer (score 0):

We can use strtok as suggested. Take a look at this code. To ease it out, im using vector in c++, please use other containers or data structures like array initialized to max of length of the two strings to hold the tokenized elements.

```
vector<char*> tokenize(char *s)
{
    vector<char*> svec;

    char *stp = strtok(s,".");
    while(stp != NULL)
    {
            svec.push_back(stp);
            stp = strtok(NULL,".");
    }
    cout << endl;
    return svec;

}

int version_compare(char *s1, char *s2)
{
    vector<char*> tokens_s1 = tokenize(s1);
    vector<char*> tokens_s2 = tokenize(s2);

    int st1, st2, flag, maxf,result;
    st1 = tokens_s1.size();
    st2 = tokens_s2.size();
    flag = st1 < st2 ? st1 : st2;


    for(int i=0; i < flag ;i++)
    {

            int one = *(tokens_s1[i]);
            int two = *(tokens_s2[i]);
            if(one > two)
                     return 1;
            else if(one < two)
                    return 2;
            else
                    result = 0;

    }
}

    if((st1 == st2) && (result == 0)) return 0;
    return (st1 > st2 ? 1 : 2);



}


int main()
{
    char s1[] = "1.2.3.4";
    char s2[] = "2.2.3.3.3";
    int st;
    st = version_compare(s1,s2);
    cout<<st<<endl;

}
```

Comment: This answer is **C++** and not **C**.

Comment: That what I've indicated in the statement. I'm using only vectors from C++, you could replace that with arrays in C

Comment: There is a C++ counterpart of this question where this answer might be more valued: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33135019

Answer (score 0):

A minimalist C version that only tokenizes the first non-matching component. Uses strchr() and strtoul().

```
int version_compare(char *s1, char *s2)
{
    char *delim = ".:-";
    while(1) {
        if (*s1 == *s2)  {
            if (!*s1)
                return 0;
            s1++; s2++;
        } else if (strchr(delim, *s1) || !*s1) {
            return -1;
        } else if (strchr(delim, *s2) || !*s2) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            int diff;
            char *end1, *end2;
            diff = strtoul(c1, &end1, 10) - strtoul(c2, &end2, 10);
            if (!diff) {
                c1 += (end1 - c1);
                c2 += (end2 - c2);
            } else {
                return diff;
            }
        }
    }
}
```