# Winows installer (wix) install product twice

Tags: c#, wix, windows-installer

I use WIX to install test product. It's very siple with default wix settigs.

If I set product id="*", install, rebuild and instal again, i have TWO products in programs list. Why?

my product:

```
<Product Id="*" Name="SetupProject1" Language="1033" Version="1.0.6.4" Manufacturer="Timyrlan" UpgradeCode="B3CB410C-6D45-44F0-9920-81E43A54B3ED">
```

P.S. same problem if i change 4-th digit of version. And everything works fine if i change 3 digit

1.0.0.0->1.0.0.1 - problem

1.0.0.0->1.0.1.0 - works fine

Why it's instal twice? How can i upgrade product using last digit?

Comment: Forgot a couple of important links below, please have another look.

Answer (score 3):

***Ignoring Digits***: Extract from the MSI SDK documentation for the [**`ProductVersion property`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/msi/productversion):

"*`Note that Windows Installer uses only the first three fields of the product version. If you include a fourth field in your product version, the installer ignores the fourth field...At least one of the three fields of ProductVersion must change for an upgrade using the Upgrade table.`*"

[***AllowSameVersionUpgrades***](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/majorupgrade.html): There is the WiX concept: [`AllowSameVersionUpgrades="yes"`](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/majorupgrade.html) - which I do not like - that some people use to allow upgrades with the 4th digit used. I do not have a list of all the problems that result (again: I don't like this concept). Maybe have a look here: [Wix MajorUpgrade problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19440846/wix-majorupgrade-problems).

***Advanced Upgrade Table***: Forgot one important link. How to gain fine-grained control of the Upgrade table: [Adding entries to MSI UpgradeTable to remove related products](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51801570/adding-entries-to-msi-upgradetable-to-remove-related-products/51803320#51803320). And the issue of downgrades: [Run Wix Custom action only during uninstall and not during Major upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51075759/run-wix-custom-action-only-during-uninstall-and-not-during-major-upgrade/51090120#51090120).

***Further Helpful Links***:

- **[WIX does not uninstall older version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56989906/wix-does-not-uninstall-older-version/56991527#56991527)** (a list of common problems with major upgrades)
- [WiX Tips and Tricks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25004226/msi-vs-nuget-packages-which-are-is-better-for-continuous-delivery/25005864#25005864) (lots of further links on WiX in general)
- [How do I avoid common design flaws in my WiX / MSI deployment solution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45840086/how-do-i-avoid-common-design-flaws-in-my-wix-msi-deployment-solution/45840087) (beware of common MSI / WiX design flaws)

---

***Links***:

- [WIX (remove all previous versions)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51404270/wix-remove-all-previous-versions) (uninstall by productcode, upgradecode, productname)
- [Doing Major Upgrade in Wix creates 2 entries in Add/Remove Programs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48745912/doing-major-upgrade-in-wix-creates-2-entries-in-add-remove-programs/48761048#48761048) (Major Upgrade - "The Old, Manual Way")
- [Installshield major upgrade doesn't uninstall old version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48042983/installshield-major-upgrade-doesnt-uninstall-old-version/48043430#48043430) (MSI API calls)